# running command under another process context

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I would like to create a new file in my process, but not under my process context, but under the context of another process (e.g. exploer.exe/cmd.exe). I can use CreateProcess with "cmd.exe /c create_file_command", but its too "heavy" for me to create a new process only for such task. is there any way to ask explorer.exe in the current user session to run a command for me?

Comment: Post what you've attempted, please.

Comment: Why do you care which process created the file? Giving us context may help us help you better.

Comment: @user, wait. Do you want to `create a new file in your process, but not under your process context`, or to `ask explorer.exe in the current user session to run a command for you`? These are mutually exclusive. (Downvote is not mine, this comment was posted in good faith.)

Comment: You could probably inject a dll into the other app that will allow you to do this; which is pretty much the only way you can get an arbitrary process to perform arbitrary tasks

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it's less important what *process* does this, and primarily matters what *user* account it's done under.

If that's so, you probably want to have your process impersonate the correct user with [`ImpersonateLoggedOnuser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612.aspx), create the file, then [`RevertToSelf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379317.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you have enough privileges. If you have not then use [CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which works almost same.

Comment: Why would you not generally prefer to use `CreateProcessWithLogon`?

Comment: @CodyGray It's funny but MSDN says to do so. Well, CreateProcessWithLogon (as it's ASCII version CreateProcessWithLogonA) even not documented.

Comment: Yes, MSDN says to prefer CreateProcessWithLogon. Why are you recommending otherwise?

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry, I wanted to say another thing. Check [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation. They wrote there to use CreateProcessWithLogonW in case CreateProcessAsUser fails.

Comment: This is specifically what the OP says is too "heavy". He wants e.g. the current user's `explorer.exe` to perform the file creation. Not a new process (as far as I understand the question).